compute new datetime dataframe column
I want to create a new datetime column in a python dataframe.
First data point is a given time stamp with the format
print(sinfo.BeginTime)
2021-07-08T08:56:46.637
Name: BeginTime, dtype: object

All subsequent times are calculated based on this first timestamp and a continuous column deltaTime, which contains seconds with some decimal places and is of type
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> and looks like that:
index    deltaT
2374     1.20047
2374     1.20047
2376     1.14953
2377     1.14413
2378     1.15073
          ...   
10537    1.14900
10538    1.15000
10539    1.10000
10540    1.25100
10541    1.10000
Name: deltaT, Length: 7108, dtype: float64

How can I connect the two data types? My code does not seem to work:
#convert deltaT into datetime format
df.deltaT = pd.to_datetime(df.deltaT, unit='s')

This gives not exactly what I expected (as there is still a date different from 0.0.000 what would mean, If I add it to the date of today I would get a date far in the future...:
RadioRxTimePk
2374    1970-01-01 00:00:01.200469999
2374    1970-01-01 00:00:01.200469999
2376    1970-01-01 00:00:01.149530000
2377    1970-01-01 00:00:01.144130000
2378    1970-01-01 00:00:01.150730000
                     ...             
10537   1970-01-01 00:00:01.148999999
10538   1970-01-01 00:00:01.149999999
10539   1970-01-01 00:00:01.100000000
10540   1970-01-01 00:00:01.251000000
10541   1970-01-01 00:00:01.100000000
Name: deltaT, Length: 7108, dtype: datetime64[ns]

If I add a test time stamp, there is a Type error:
# make a new column and 
df['time'] = df.testdatetime + df.deltaT

TypeError: cannot add DatetimeArray and DatetimeArray

as expected...
Any hint?

It would be best to provide code to set up a [mre] (not just a text representation)

Use df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['testdatetime']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['deltaT'], unit='s')

@jezreal: this worked! pd.to_timedelta was the solution I was looking for! Thank you once more :-)
